# why does my second block stick to the first?

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]

I am beginner in CSS, I don't understand why my second text isn't at the bottom of the first block?
Why my 2 blocks are horizontally? Normally, the second text must be towards the bottom?!

My structure in HTML seems to be correct?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">
      <img class="img-icon" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/13/937l.png" /> 
      <div class="t-title-first">my first text </div> 
      <div class="t-title-second">my second text</div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help and your time.

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 35px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;

}
.img-icon{
  width: 15%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 15px;
}

.col{
  display: flex;
  width: 25%;
}

.t-title-first{
  padding: 15px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: blue;
}

.t-title-second{
  padding: 15px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">
      <img class="img-icon" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/13/937l.png" /> 
      <div class="t-title-first">my first text </div> 
      <div class="t-title-second">my second text</div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col">
      <img class="img-icon" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/13/937l.png" /> 
      <div class="t-title-first">my first text </div>
      <div class="t-title-second">my second text</div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col">
      <img class="img-icon" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/13/937l.png" /> 
      <div class="t-title-first">my first text </div>
      <div class="t-title-second">my second text</div>
    </div>
  
  
   
      
    
</div>
```

Comment: You've told the `col` elements to act like a row with `display:flex`...why would you expect them to act like a column?

Comment: Wrap your `title` divs in their own div,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by wrapping the text in a simple div.

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 35px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;

}
.img-icon{
  width: 15%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 15px;
}

.col{
  display: flex;
  width: 25%;
}

.t-title-first{
  padding: 15px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: blue;
}

.t-title-second{
  padding: 15px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">
      <img class="img-icon" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/13/937l.png" /> 
      <div>
        <div class="t-title-first">my first text </div>
        <div class="t-title-second">my second text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col">
      <img class="img-icon" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/13/937l.png" /> 
      <div>
        <div class="t-title-first">my first text </div>
        <div class="t-title-second">my second text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col">
      <img class="img-icon" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/13/937l.png" /> 
      <div>
        <div class="t-title-first">my first text </div>
        <div class="t-title-second">my second text</div>
      </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```